# When running a Django test I get "Data truncated for column 'name' at row 30"

Tags: mysql, django

I'm in charge of alot of Django legacy code and a part of this code is some old tests that they used to run but are now most likely outdated.  I tried to run the tests with "./manage.py test" but I get this warning when creating the database "Data truncated for column 'name' at row 30" and then the test cancels itself.

I thought maybe its because of some old test fixtures so I created a simple dummy test in an app's test.py file but I get the same error when I run it.  Below is the dummy test:

```
class TestingTheTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(),'FOO')
```

I understand that when you run a test a test database is created.  But why am I getting "Data truncated for column 'name' at row 30"?  Is there an issue with creating the database tables? Is it trying to populate the tables upon creation?  How can I isolate the problem because "Data truncated for column 'name' at row 30" is very vague.

My actual database works fine so I'm not sure why this test database is having issues.

Comment: You should include your models and the setUp

Comment: There are probably 100+ models spread across 10 different apps and the problem is I have no idea which one of those models is causing the error when they all seem to work fine in our dev and production.

Comment: Include a model that has `name` as field...also it's possible you have a stacktrace

Comment: Here is the stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/9Gw4fQpV

We use the field 'name' in an abstract model that is used in numerous different models.  I use this same method of using an abstract class for name in other projects and those aren't having this problem so I'm not sure if thats it.

Comment: I think you created a permission with name greater than 30 characters. Ring a bell?

Comment: Not really but then again this could have been from 5 years ago before I was here lol.  I'll investigate.

Comment: Thank you it looks like that was what the issue was.  I saw permissions were in traceback too but I didn't think antyhing of it.

Comment: It happens to everyone. Take care